# android upload image to amazon storage with image path

Tags: android, image, amazon-web-services

I want to upload a image using it's file path. Most of the tutorial I have followed regarding upload image to amazon, there is select image option(image chooser from galary). But what i need is that:

But I want to skip this step. As I know the image path and name. Suppose I have a image in a directory in the device. When user click upload photo button, it will start uploading. I want to skip select image option. But  How Can I upload  image to amazon storage with image path instead of selecting image (`Intent image/*`)?

So in short I am just wanting to use file path directly instead of select image option to upload the image in amazon.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edited:**

Here is my activity:

```
public class SubmitActivity extends Activity {

Button submit;
ImageView thumbnailimage;
private AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
        new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                Constants.SECRET_KEY));

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
    setContentView(R.layout.submit);

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsubmit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + File.separator + "cubicasa.jpg");
            new S3PutObjectTask().execute(selectedImage);
        }
    });
    thumbnailimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbimg);

    byte[] imageData = null;

    try {

        final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 150;
        // InputStream is=getAssets().open("apple-android-battle.jpg");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + File.separator
                + "cubicasa.jpg");
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

        Float width = new Float(imageBitmap.getWidth());
        Float height = new Float(imageBitmap.getHeight());
        Float ratio = width / height;
        imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap,
                (int) (THUMBNAIL_SIZE * ratio), THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        imageData = baos.toByteArray();
        thumbnailimage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}

private class S3PutObjectTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, S3TaskResult> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(SubmitActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage(SubmitActivity.this.getString(R.string.uploading));
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected S3TaskResult doInBackground(Uri... uris) {

        if (uris == null || uris.length != 1) {
            return null;
        }

        // The file location of the image selected.
        Uri selectedImage = uris[0];

        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        String fileSizeColumn[] = { OpenableColumns.SIZE };

        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(selectedImage, fileSizeColumn, null,
                null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        // If the size is unknown, the value stored is null. But since an
        // int can't be
        // null in java, the behavior is implementation-specific, which is
        // just a fancy
        // term for "unpredictable". So as a rule, check if it's null before
        // assigning
        // to an int. This will happen often: The storage API allows for
        // remote
        // files, whose size might not be locally known.
        String size = null;
        if (!cursor.isNull(sizeIndex)) {
            // Technically the column stores an int, but cursor.getString
            // will do the
            // conversion automatically.
            size = cursor.getString(sizeIndex);
        }

        cursor.close();

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType(resolver.getType(selectedImage));
        if (size != null) {
            metadata.setContentLength(Long.parseLong(size));
        }

        S3TaskResult result = new S3TaskResult();

        // Put the image data into S3.
        try {
            s3Client.createBucket(Constants.getPictureBucket());

            PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(
                    Constants.getPictureBucket(), Constants.PICTURE_NAME,
                    resolver.openInputStream(selectedImage), metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(por);
        } catch (Exception exception) {

            result.setErrorMessage(exception.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(S3TaskResult result) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        if (result.getErrorMessage() != null) {

            displayErrorAlert(
                    SubmitActivity.this
                            .getString(R.string.upload_failure_title),
                    result.getErrorMessage());
        }
    }
}

protected void displayErrorAlert(String title, String message) {

    AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    confirm.setTitle(title);
    confirm.setMessage(message);

    confirm.setNegativeButton(
            SubmitActivity.this.getString(R.string.ok),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    SubmitActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });

    confirm.show().show();
}

private class S3TaskResult {
    String errorMessage = null;
    Uri uri = null;

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
}

}
```

Here is my log cat error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Uri uriImg =Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
+ "/Images/img1.jpg");  

    PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest( Constants.getPictureBucket(),      

    Constants.PICTURE_NAME, new java.io.File( uriImg) );  
    s3Client.putObject( por );
```

I hpoe this help:

Comment: what will be Constants.getPictureBucket(), Constants.PICTURE_NAME,  Constants.PICTURE_BUCKET?

Comment: Brother, please check my question again. I got some error there. Plz.