# I have multiple image path (URI/String) how do i upload them to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-asynctask

I have multiple image's path (URI / String). By passing this value to " S3PutObjectTask().execute(URI); " i want to upload all those images to Amazon S3.
Could some one help me how to pass those URIs also how to upload multiple images.

Similar log cat error is found in [android upload image to amazon storage with image path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292957/android-upload-image-to-amazon-storage-with-image-path)

Thanks in advance

```
    public class AWSUpload extends Activity {

private AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
        new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                Constants.SECRET_KEY));

String uri1a, uri2a, uri3a, uri4a;
int i;
private static final int PHOTO_SELECTED = 1;
Button b1;
TextView t1, t2, t3, t4;
ImageView iv1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inspectionreport);
    s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
    Intent gettingURI = getIntent();
    uri1a = gettingURI.getStringExtra("uri1");
    uri2a = gettingURI.getStringExtra("uri2");
    uri3a = gettingURI.getStringExtra("uri3");
    uri4a = gettingURI.getStringExtra("uri4");
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Uri img1URI = Uri.parse(uri1a);
    Uri img2URI = Uri.parse(uri2a);
    Uri img3URI = Uri.parse(uri3a);
    Uri img4URI = Uri.parse(uri4a);
    t1.setText(uri1a);
    t2.setText(uri2a);
    t3.setText(uri3a);
    t4.setText(uri4a);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    Uri selectedImage1 = Uri.parse(uri1a);
                    new S3PutObjectTask().execute(selectedImage1);
                } else if (i == 2) {
                    Uri selectedImage2 = Uri.parse(uri2a);
                    new S3PutObjectTask().execute(selectedImage2);
                } else if (i == 3) {
                    Uri selectedImage3 = Uri.parse(uri3a);
                    new S3PutObjectTask().execute(selectedImage3);
                } else if (i == 4) {
                    Uri selectedImage4 = Uri.parse(uri4a);
                    new S3PutObjectTask().execute(selectedImage4);
                } else {
                    Intent returnIntent = new Intent(AWSUpload.this,
                            ProductImagesss.class);
                    startActivity(returnIntent);
                }

            }

        }
    });


}

// This method is automatically called by the image picker when an image is
// selected.
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case PHOTO_SELECTED:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            new S3PutObjectTask().execute(selectedImage);
        }
    }
}

// Display an Alert message for an error or failure.
protected void displayAlert(String title, String message) {

    AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    confirm.setTitle(title);
    confirm.setMessage(message);

    confirm.setNegativeButton(AWSUpload.this.getString(R.string.ok),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    confirm.show().show();
}

protected void displayErrorAlert(String title, String message) {

    AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    confirm.setTitle(title);
    confirm.setMessage(message);

    confirm.setNegativeButton(AWSUpload.this.getString(R.string.ok),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    AWSUpload.this.finish();
                }
            });

    confirm.show().show();
}

private class S3PutObjectTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, S3TaskResult> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(AWSUpload.this);
        dialog.setMessage(AWSUpload.this.getString(R.string.uploading));
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected S3TaskResult doInBackground(Uri... uris) {

        if (uris == null || uris.length != 1) {
            return null;
        }

        // The file location of the image selected.
        Uri selectedImage = uris[0];

        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        String fileSizeColumn[] = { OpenableColumns.SIZE };

        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(selectedImage, fileSizeColumn, null,
                null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        String size = null;
        if (!cursor.isNull(sizeIndex)) {

            size = cursor.getString(sizeIndex);
        }

        cursor.close();

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType(resolver.getType(selectedImage));
        if (size != null) {
            metadata.setContentLength(Long.parseLong(size));
        }

        S3TaskResult result = new S3TaskResult();

        // Put the image data into S3.
        try {
            // s3Client.createBucket(Constants.getPictureBucket());

            PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest("mybucket",
                    Constants.PICTURE_NAME,
                    resolver.openInputStream(selectedImage), metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(por);
        } catch (Exception exception) {

            result.setErrorMessage(exception.getMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(S3TaskResult result) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        if (result.getErrorMessage() != null) {

            displayErrorAlert(
                    AWSUpload.this.getString(R.string.upload_failure_title),
                    result.getErrorMessage());
        }
    }
}

private class S3TaskResult {
    String errorMessage = null;
    Uri uri = null;

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
}
```

}

My Log Cat:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at com.cbazaarqc.AWSUpload$S3PutObjectTask.doInBackground(AWSUpload.java:229)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at com.cbazaarqc.AWSUpload$S3PutObjectTask.doInBackground(AWSUpload.java:1)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
 E/AndroidRuntime(18015):   ... 4 more
 E/WindowManager(18015): Activity com.cbazaarqc.AWSUpload has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{420a16e0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
 E/WindowManager(18015): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.cbazaarqc.AWSUpload has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{420a16e0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:218)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at com.cbazaarqc.AWSUpload$S3PutObjectTask.onPreExecute(AWSUpload.java:211)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at com.cbazaarqc.AWSUpload.onCreate(AWSUpload.java:93)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 E/WindowManager(18015):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you have a null pointer exception at AWSUpload.java:229.  we cant see line numbers to see which line that is.

Comment: look at the aws TransferManager.  There is a function uploadFileList which takes a list of files to be uploaded [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html)

Comment: hi @pwilmot  AWSUpload.java:229 is `cursor.moveToFirst();`   `AWSUpload.java:297 private class S3TaskResult {  AWSUpload.java:298 String errorMessage = null;  AWSUpload.java:299 Uri uri = null;

Comment: you have a null pointer exception in that line so you should make sure the cursor isn't null?

Comment: @pwilmot  I am not using any database or SELECT here so do i still have to use this cursor. If not can you guide me as what can be done

Comment: My Problem Solved

As I am not using any database nor any SELECT i removed using cursor.
Hope the method is good to follow.

Comment: things are all set now?

Comment: @pwilmot 
ya its some what solved now i have issues in upload images to Amazon S3 it shows upload failure : encountered exception couldnt retry.

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: I get the error in dialog box
stated as
"Encountered an exception and couldn't reset the stream to retry"

When i checked in github i came to know this message is returned as a result of **"resetRequestAfterError()"**

Will be helpfull if you could tel me how to pass the image url `(/storage/sdcard0/Picrtures....)` to upload the image on to amazon s3